# 403 Forbidden while configuring apache/httpd server

Tags: apache, web, webserver, server

I have installed httpd in my rhel6 with `"yum install httpd"`
after starting the server with `"service httpd start"`, I am trying to access the test page with wget http://localhost:8080 (this i have configured in my httpd.conf), I am getting **403 Access forbidden**. Can any1 help me why i am getting this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check directory permissions in httpd.conf:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options +Indexes FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
    AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo
            Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

where "/var/www/html" is your document root.